# Can anyone do vertical slide on orbit using foundation 5?

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, orbit

I can't do vertical slide in orbit, using foundation 5. The only type of animation that works is animation:'slide'. I opened the orbit js file, and realized that only this option was contemplated, regardless of the documentation on the official site, which implies that I could use fade, vertical-slide and others. Has anyone been successful in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that foundation has taken the animations from this plugins...